# Backbone.js Collection.models not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, hamlc

I have a Rails project with Backbone.js and HAML as client side templating language.

in file app/assets/views/meeting.coffee:

```
class window.MeetingIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['meeting/index']

  render: ->
    @collection.fetch()
    @$el.html(@template(collection: @collection))
    this
```

in file app/assets/javascripts/templates/meeting/index.hamlc

```
- console.log(@collection.length) # prints 0 in console
- console.log(@collection.models) # prints [] in console
- console.log(@collection.at(0))  # prints undefined in console
- window.x =  @collection
```

if I go to the browser console I get:

```
x.length # returns 2
x.models # returns [Meeting, Meeting]
x.at(0)  # returns Meeting object
```

If I can access @collection variable in .hamlc file, because I am assigning it to window.x. Why can't I access the @collection items from the .hamlc file?

I need something like

```
- for model in @collection.models
  %p= model.get('landlord_id')
  %p= model.get('tenant_id')
  %p= model.get('at')
```

to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Collection#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) method is asynchronous (i.e. it is an AJAX call behind the curtains) so `@collection.fetch()` hasn't gotten anything back from the server when you try to use it in your view. However:

> The **options** hash takes `success` and `error` callbacks which will be passed `(collection, response)` as arguments. When the model data returns from the server, the collection will reset.

So you can use the callbacks:

```
render: ->
  @collection.fetch(
    success: (collection, response) =>
      @$el.html(@template(collection: @collection))
  @
```

Or you can bind the view's `render` to the collection's `reset` event:

```
class window.MeetingIndex extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['meeting/index']
  initialize: ->
    @collection.on('reset', @render)
    @collection.fetch()
  render: =>
    @$el.html(@template(collection: @collection))
    @
```

Then the `fetch` call in the view's `initialize` would indirectly trigger the proper `render` call when it gets something back from the server. This approach works best if your template knows what to do with an empty collection, perhaps it could detect an empty collection and display a "loading" message or just say "nothing's here yet".